# MIPS assembly: Why can main exit without deallocating its stack space?

Tags: c, assembly, mips, callstack

I have a question for a university exercise that I don't understand. We have to translate from C to assembly MIPS. In the main I have to allocate 400 bytes for the `a[100]` vector, but in the solutions my professor is not deallocating it at the end of the function, why is this happening? are there cases in which I don't need to deallocate memory moving stack pointer?

Here's the code in C:

```
 int idamax(int n, float * dx, int incx) {
     float dmax;
     int i, ix, itemp;
     if (n < 1) return (-1);
     if (n == 1) return (0);
     if (incx != 1) {
         ix = 1;
         dmax = fabs(dx[0]);
         ix = ix + incx;
         for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
             if (dmax < fabs(dx[ix])) {
                 itemp = i;
                 dmax = fabs(dx[ix]);
             }
             ix = ix + incx;
         }
     } else {
         itemp = 0;
         dmax = fabs(dx[0]);
         for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
             if (dmax < fabs(dx[i])) {
                 itemp = i;
                 dmax = fabs(dx[i]);
             }
         }
     }
     return (itemp);
 }
 int main() {
     float a[100];
     int l, k, n = 100, lda = 10;
     for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) a[k] = (float)((k * k * k) % 100);
     k = 4;
     l = idamax(n - lda * k - k, &a[lda * k + k], 1) + k;
     print_int(l);
     exit;
 }
```

Main assembly code:

```
main:
#______CALL_FRAME______
# 100 float: 400B
#______Totale 400B
 addi $sp,$sp,-400
 add $t9,$sp,$0 #&a
 addi $t0, $0, 100 #n=100
 addi $t1, $0, 10 #lda=10
#l in t2, k in t3

 add $t3, $0, $0 #k=0
main_forini:
 slt $t5,$t3,$t0 #k<?n
 beq $t5,$0,main_forend

 mult $t3, $t3 #k*k
 mflo $t5
 mult $t3, $t5
 mflo $t5 #k*k*k
 div $t5,$t0 #()%n
 mfhi $t5

 mtc1 $t5,$f0
 cvt.s.w $f1,$f0 #(float)()

 sll $t5,$t3,2 #k*4
 add $t5,$t5,$t9 #&a[k]
 swc1 $f1,0($t5) #a[k]=()

 addi $t3, $t3, 1 #++k
 j main_forini
main_forend:
 addi $t3,$0,4 #k=4
 mult $t1,$t3 #lda*k
 mflo $t5
 add $t5,$t5,$t3 #lda*k+k
 sub $a0,$t0,$t5 #a0=n-lda*k-k
 sll $t5,$t5,2
 add $a1,$t5,$t9 #a1=&a[lda*k+k]
 addi $a2,$0,1 #a2=1
 jal idamax
 addi $a0,$v0,4 #a0=l=retval+k
 addi $v0,$0,1 #print_int
 syscall
 addi $v0,$0,10 #exit
 syscall
```

Comment: It would be better to include a minimal MIPS example that shows what you mean. The C code is irrelevant to the question except that it has `float a[100]` on the stack.

Comment: Sorry, i added my professor solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution of `main` never reaches the bottom of the function so cleanup of the stack never needs to happen; `exit()` is a "noreturn" function.

If `main` *did* want to return with `jr $ra` instead of making an `exit` system call, you would need to restore the stack pointer along with other call-preserved registers.  Otherwise you'd be violating the calling convention that `main`'s caller expects `main` to follow.

(Updated since you added asm to the question that uses a MARS system call: that `main` is probably not a function if it's the top of your code: `$ra` isn't a valid return address on entry so it couldn't return.  IMO don't call it `main` if it's not a function.)

**The OS doesn't care where the user-space stack pointer is pointing when the process makes an exit system call, so there's no need for `main` to clean up before exiting.**

(In a "normal" C implementation, the `exit()` function would compile to a `jal exit` or a simple tailcall `j exit`.  But you're compiling by hand for the MARS simulator which has no C library, so you inline system calls instead of calling wrapper functions.)

Also note that ISO C `exit(int)` takes an arg, like [MARS `exit2` (`syscall`/`$v0=17`)](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html).  In fact you didn't even call `exit()` as a function, you just wrote `exit;` in C which evaluates the `exit` as a function pointer without calling it or doing anything with that value.

---

Typically C `main` is called by CRT startup code that might for example run C library init functions and put argc and an argv[] pointer in the right registers.  So `main` is usually not the actual process entry point from the OS, especially not in a hosted implementation.  (i.e. compiled C programs run under an OS, rather than being their own kernel like a freestanding program.)

If you're just translating this for the MARS or SPIM simulators or something, then there is no C library or any code beyond what you write, **so what you're writing is what would normally be called `_start`, not `main`.**

In C `main` is a function, but in MARS [you can't `jr $ra` from the top-level entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727971/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-the-main-function-in-mips) so **the entry point is not a function**.  Thus don't call it `main`.

In ISO C it's even legal for `main` to call itself recursively, or other functions to call `main`.  That can only work if main truly is a function that cleans up the stack and returns properly.  But that means it can't also be the process entry point that needs to make an `exit` system call.  To run a program with a crazy recursive main that eventually does a C `return` statement (or falls off the end of main), main pretty much has to be compiled to a real function that can return with `jr $ra`.  So it has to be a function that you `jal main` to from your `_start` entry point.

Comment: The alternative to calling `main` from CRT startup code is to call that CRT startup code in from `main`. The C standard makes `main` special so these tricks are possible, the challenge is to make sure that you can call `main` recursively.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers here.

The first answer is that `main` is the first and last function of your program. The OS will clean up afterwards.

The second answer would be for other functions that use stack memory. Stack memory is generally freed by restoring the stack frame of the calling function (which `main` doesn't have, hence the exception).

Comment: If `main` is truly the entry point and can't exit with `jr $ra` even if it wants to, *it's not a function*.  IMO the real answer is that it calls a noreturn function instead of reaching the bottom of main.  (Precisely because you can't let it reach the bottom in an implementation where `main` is sloppily used as a label for the entry point with no valid return address in `$ra`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: It's quite possible that `main` is not a real function. E.g. on Windows, you need to call `ExitProcess(retval)` to return a value to the OS. The normal call convention doesn't work there. But that's an implementation choice. Another valid choice is to have a `__crtMain` entry point which calls `main` using normal C semantics.

Comment: In Linux the process entry point is also not a function, but nobody calls it `main` (exactly *because* it's not a function).  So my real objection here is to calling something `main` when you *can't* return from from it.  If you could but choose not to, that's fine, e.g. calling `exit(0)`  from C `main`.  MSVC's asm output for `int main(){}` returns with `ret`.  https://godbolt.org/z/rS0YQM.  So I guess it's compiled for option 2, where C `main` is not the entry point.  But you're claiming it's normal or at least not insane to call something `main` if it can only exit via a noreturn function?

Comment: MSVC primarily is a C++ compiler, and that means it needs to support global constructors running before `main`, as well as destructors after `main`. That's why it uses `mainCRTStartup`. Also, since it's a C++, compiler, it uses C++ to call `main`. Not a big secret, that CRT code is shipped with Visual Studio (see exe_common.inl). But yes, I think that we can still call `main` `main` if the compiler inlined some instructions that make it `noreturn`, e.g. by inlining an `exit()` call and removing the resulting unreachable `ret`.