# Assembly fibonacci returns correct result, but crashes on last iteration

Tags: assembly, mips

I've written the following assembly code for the fibonacci function. It works in that the correct result is placed in $v0 upon termination, but the program also crashes with the exception `Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000`

This is my code:

```
main:
    li $a0, 5
    j fib

fib: 
    bgt $a0, 1, body     # continue if $a0 is larger than 1
    addi $v0, $zero, 1   # else return 1
    jr $ra               # return to body

body:
    addi $sp, $sp, -16 # make room for 4 registers in stack
    sw $a0, 0($sp)     # save $a0 = n, to stack
    sw $ra, 4($sp)     # save return address to stack

    addi $a0, $a0, -1  # $a0 =  n - 1
    jal fib            # invoke fib(n-1) and save return address
    sw $v0, 8($sp)     # $v0 = fib(n-1), save to stack

    lw $a0, 0($sp)     # reset argument to original
    addi $a0, $a0, -2  # $a0 = n - 2  
    jal fib            # invoke fib(n-2) and save return address
    sw $v0, 12($sp)    # $v0 = fib(n-2), save to stack

    lw $t0, 8($sp)     # $t0 = fib(n-1)
    lw $t1, 12($sp)    # $t1 = fib(n-2)
    lw $ra, 4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16  # pop from stack

    add $v0, $t0, $t1  # $v0 = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

    jr $ra             # jump to return address
```

Any advice on how to my program work without crashing? much appreciated

Comment: Did you look here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826935/invalid-program-counter-value-0

Comment: Yes didn't work because i use recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow the execution of `fib(1)` through your program, and see why it fails:

```
main:
    li $a0, 1            # edited for brevity...
    j fib                # make a note here.

fib: 
    bgt $a0, 1, body     # won't branch...
    addi $v0, $zero, 1   # else return 1
    jr $ra               # return to caller?
```

this crashes, because you used `j fib` in `main()`. The contents of `$ra` are those of `main()`, which luckily happens to be an invalid value so you crash instead of executing weird code somewhere.
*But it gets worse*. Even if you replace `j fib` with the correct `jal fib`, you're still going to have problems after the return, as `main()` doesn't terminate (syscall or return), or loop, but rather continues into `fib()`. That's going to hurt.

Comment: Hmm, so my whole approach is wrong or how would you advice i fixed it? sorry, I'm very new to assembly

Comment: @Tarlen: No, your approach is fine. You need to change `j fib` to `jal fib` and write some more code in `main()`. When `main()` is finished, it needs to make a `syscall` that tells the OS to terminate it. It could also `return` (jr $ra), but it seems that your system doesn't let `main()` end that way. It's implementation-defined. `main()` could also be written in an infinite loop, if  that is what you want. The easiest thing would be the `syscall`.

Comment: I tried adding the jal fib and syscall to main, but now the program runs in an infinite loop

Comment: @Tarlen: ...which I predicted. The label `fib:` follows right after `jal fib` in `main:`, so after returning, the processor continues executing into fib *again*. You need to make sure `main()` does something after `jal fib`. Only you know *what* you want `main()` to do, and only you know what platform your code is running on. Do you have an operating system? If so, which one? What ABI and `syscall`s does your OS provide?